# CEFSharp Resource loaded event

Tags: .net, wpf, chromium-embedded

I am looking for something to intercept the response of a resource loaded. For example an image. I am aware the `OnResourceResponse` method in the `CefSharp.IRequestHandler` is not available. See this link: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/IRequestHandler.cs#L37

Is there any other way I can intercept a resource loaded? I only need to know if the request is ready, and what URL it contains. I do not mind about the content.